# Can SharePoint 2013 search ignore dashes in filenames?

Tags: 2013, search

In our SharePoint 2013 farm we have many metadata containing dashes, e. g. `acd-200`.

In document names, the dash is unfortunately often left out, so a document like `acd200_2015_03.pdf` is about the object `acd-200`.

Is it possible to configure the Search Center in SharePoint 2013 Standard to consider those 2 strings `acd-200` and `acd200` as synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

Hyphen is a word breaker for SharePoint's Search indexer, so "acd-200" is stored as two terms "acd" and "200" separately.

What you can do is **use custom word breaker**, but it's not easy and intensive testing should be done. See http://www.getsharepointsolutions.com/searching-hyphenated-words-in-sharepoint-server-2013/ and other sources

**Or** you can **create a thesaurus**. First, create a `.csv` file with the columns `Key`, `Synonym` and `Language` (this one is optional), comma-separated, UTF8:

> Key,Synonym,Language
>
> UN,United Nations,en
>
> acd-200,acd200

Then, deploy it to server with powershell:

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication 
Import-SPEnterpriseSearchThesaurus -SearchApplication $searchApp -Filename <Path_To_CSV>
```

This might help. Process is described in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219579.aspx.

PS. Actually, it's better to name files *without* `-` for search

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the Content Processing Callout. Create a web service that handles the transformation for you.

1. Essentially you create the web service according to this spec:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163968.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
2. Then Create a trigger based on the metadata you are looking to
   change. SharePoint will send the content to your service for
   processing BEFORE it goes into the word breaker.
3. Finally your code modifies the necessary values and returns them to
   the indexer.